# android:read gmail contact's full sized photo

Tags: android, photo, contacts

I trying to read and show contact's full sized photo on a Imageview. Below code worked well in emulator which has contacts locally created.

while testing this on Attrix 4G which has contacts synced from gmail, it doesnt show the full sized contacts.

```
    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
    Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);

    AssetFileDescriptor fd = cr.openAssetFileDescriptor(
                displayPhotoUri, "r");
        input = fd.createInputStream();
return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

From my reading, the problem is simply because Gmail isn't syncing a hi-res version of the photo, particularly for older devices/API levels.

So while your code would work if the photo were available, the call to openAssetFileDescriptor will fail because there is no corresponding hi-res file.

Refer to this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3870&q=contact%20photo&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) reported against Android (incorrectly?).

Answer (score 1):

some how above piece of code is working for me on Nexus 4.

```
 ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
    PersonUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 3347);
    Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PersonUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);
     try {
        AssetFileDescriptor fd = cr.openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r");
        input = fd.createInputStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, PersonUri);

    if(input != null){
        showImage(mPhoto, BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input));
    }else{
        showImage(mPhoto, R.drawable.jb_picture_unknown);
    }
```